# Backbone View Attribute Hash Not Updating

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

Hopefully I'm missing something simple... I'm trying to do something basic in that I want a view's attribute hash to update automatically when the model changes.

If you look at the **attributes:** section, you can see how i'm trying to dynamically set them. However, they don't seem to be updating with the underlying model changes.

Any ideas? Thank you!

```
NS.CP.ColorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    },
    attributes: function(){
        return {
            'class': (this.model.get('active') == 'true') ? 'active' : '',
            'data-code': this.model.get('modifier'),
            'data-hex': this.model.get('color'),
            'data-image': this.model.get('image'),
            'data-match': this.model.get('matchBody'),
            'style': 'background-color: ' + this.model.get('color')
        };
    },
    events: {
        'click': 'renderFrame',
        'activate': 'activate',
        'deactivate': 'deactivate'
    },
    tagName: 'li',
    render: function(){

        console.log(this);

        var $el = this.$el;

        if( this.model.get('active') == 'true' && $el.closest('.model_colorpicker').hasClass('body-colors') ){

            // Change border color on click
            $('.color-frame').css( 'border-color', $el.data('hex') );
        }

        return this.el;
    },
    activate: function(){
        this.model.set('active', 'true');
    },
    deactivate: function(){
        this.model.set('active', 'false');
    },
    renderFrame: function(){
        if( !this.$el.hasClass('active') ){ this.$el.trigger('activate').siblings().trigger('deactivate'); }
        else { this.$el.trigger('deactivate'); }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only time the attributes hash is calculated is when the view is created, you will need to do some work yourself to update it, here is one way,

```
initialize : function(){
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.modelChange);
},
modelChange : function(){
  this.$el.attr(_.extend({}, _.result(this, 'attributes')));
}
```